# What happened to the doc of rviz tool?

Tags: ros, rviz, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://code.ros.org/wiki/rviz

This link is found on http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=rviz

It shows that

```
 Not Found
 
 The requested URL /wiki/rviz was not found on this server.
 Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5.2 PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g Server at code.ros.org Port 80
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10556/what-happened-to-the-doc-of-rviz-tool?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-07-11**:
thanks for the report, there was a documentation error in the rviz package that was reporting the wrong URL.  arebgun's post below has the correct URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are looking for [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz) page.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1